# $\sin u\geq \frac{2u}{\pi}$ whenever $0\leq u\leq \pi/2$

Tags: trigonometry

How is it true that $\sin u\geq \frac{2u}{\pi}$ whenever $0\leq u\leq \pi/2$? I just simply cannot see how this is true though it looks very simple. Hope someone could give an answer thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

$$f(u) = \frac{\sin u}{u}$$

is decreasing on $[0,\pi/2]$ since $f'(u) = \frac{u\cos u - \sin u}{u^2} \leq 0$ so $f(u) \geq f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $$f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \frac{2}{\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to prove this is to note that sin is concave on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. A concave function is always above every segment that you can draw from one point of its curve to another.

Here the line $\frac{2u}{\pi} $ is the segment you draw from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ on the graph of sin, hence sin is above this and you get your inequality.